# String type charAt

Tags: java, string

I have two simple examples to support my question. I can't figure out why (1) is working while (2) isn't. In my opinion I use them the same way.

(1)

```
public String frontBack(String str) {
  if (str.length() <= 1) return str;

  String mid = str.substring(1, str.length()-1);

  // last + mid + first
  return str.charAt(str.length()-1) + mid + str.charAt(0);
}
```

(2)

```
public String front22(String str) {
  str = "test";
  return str.charAt(0);
}
```

With the second one, I get an type mismatch error that says: Cannot convert from char to string. When I try to find an answer on internet I see the str declared as a var type in all examples. But it works with the first example.

What am I missing?

Comment: I assumed this is java but now I just read that part about "var type"... so what language are you talking about?

Comment: The language is definitely Java (or close enough); I would guess that his use of the term is just a carry-over from his familiarity with another language.  I'm much more interested in what exactly he's trying to do, and why on earth he's trying to do it.

Comment: It is Java indeed. I forgot to tell you guys that. It's is just a real simple example of my problem in a more complex program. I thought it would be easier to understand this way.

Answer (score 4):

In the first example you return a `String`. In the second you (try to) return a `char`.

Since you do string concatenation in the first example the result of the expression is a string.

Comment: So if I understand you correct, you're saying that although str is declared as a string, with the charAt() it's about the type within the (). So if I type str.charAt(0) i try to return a char-type and with str.charAt(str.length()) I try to return a string type?

Sorry for my ignorance but I just can't figure this one out.

Comment: @user1527079 charAt returns a char. You're (trying to) return whatever is returned by charAt... a char. The function is defined a returning a string, which is not a char. In the expression with string concatenation, one of the things you concatenate is a string, so the result of the concatenation will be a string. Adding a char to a string results in another string. Since you're returning the result of the string concatenation, you're returning a string, which is what the function is defined as returning.

Comment: @user1527079 It has nothing to do with the "type within the ()"... which is an int. The method itself returns a value, the type of which is independent of the type of the method's parameters (if any).

Answer (score 0):

To return the first character as a String:

```
return str.substring(0,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by typing

```
return "" + str.charAt(0);
```

Somehow that forces the character into a string.